# WordPress - Theme changes overwritten by GoDaddy

Tags: wordpress

Greetings and thanks in advance for your feedback. Now I realize that this isn't GoDaddy tech support but I'm asking the question here before I step into those murky, black waters.

Scenario:  I edit the CSS and various templates for the default template via Appearance > Editor.  All looks and performs great.  I hand off to my client.  She reports back that after adding a new post the customizations are overwritten and the default theme files are restored!  She claims that GoDaddy told her that its "on my end."

Nonsense, right?  There is no relation between adding a post and updating theme files, right?

This is the second time this has occurred - the first time we assumed GoDaddy had backups of the customized files (not).  At least with the second occurrence, I had a local backup.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either that or the wordpress install has been upgraded, if your theme folder is still using the default then it will be overwritten by wordpress on upgrade..

if so change your default theme folder to something else...
then edit the css file and give it a new name...

Comment: Thanks Marty - let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Use FTP and a text editor to edit the theme files directly and check their permissions. I think the changes are not taking effect because you've got file permission problems, and as soon as the client forces a reload of the site, she sees the unchanged files again.

And if you're using a Windows server, consider changing to Linux. GoDaddy has lots of problems with Wordpress on Windows, from permission problems to permalinks. You can change to a Linux server in a few hours: [Switching Your Hosting Account Operating System - GoDaddy Help Center](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1285)